# Template declaration to dynamically find views in RoR

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to separate the views for the different platforms into different subfolders.

I have done this for the layout, at the moment I have the following:

class MoviesController < ApplicationController
   layout :site_layout

def site_layout
      if(iphone_request?)
         "iPhone/movies"
      else
         "movies"
   end

This means that in my action methods I don't need to include :layout, however I do still need to manually include the path to the template.

format.iphone {render :template => 'movies/iPhone/index'}

Is there a way to have the same kind of layout declaration but for templates?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to extend the `view_paths` so that you can have a special iphone subfolder under views and override templates as necessary. See [this tutorial](http://rethink.unspace.ca/2009/5/21/cascading-view-paths-for-fun-and-profit) on how to do that.

However, is there a reason you don't want to use the iphone format in the view name (`show.iphone.erb`) instead of making a subfolder? See [martinkl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284169/mobile-version-of-views-for-ruby-on-rails/1284492#1284492) in your other question for details.

Comment: The reason is because I don't want my directories to be 
/movies
 /new.html.erb
 /new.iphone.erb
 /new.wm.erb
 /new.js.erb

Wanted to try and separate them out a little bit into subfolders...

Answer (score 0):

I might be off, but maybe it'll help - try checking [`prepend_view_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000645).